# Maximum number of pairwise vertex-disjoint paths

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems, network-flow

My problem is:

Let $G$ be a graph, and let $A, B ⊆ V (G)$ (not necessarily disjoint). Prove that the
maximum number of pairwise vertex-disjoint $A$, $B$-paths in $G$ equals the minimum size of a set
$S ⊆ V (G)$ (which may intersect $A$ and $B$) such that $G − S$ contains no $A$, $B$-path.

I believe this needs to be approached using Menger's theorem but I cannot figure out how to apply it to prove this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that if $v\in A\cap B$, then we must assume that a path of length $0$ consisting only of vertex $v$ connects $A$ and $B$. Isn't it so?